# Typescript: Custom type that parallels base type ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, types

Expectation:
If I create a custom type that parallels an existing type I expect to see variables assigned that type maintain that type and not fallback to to the paralleled base type. The function `f` below should return a `Dog` type instead a `string` type.

```js
type Dog = string;

const f = (dog: Dog): Dog => {
    return dog;
};
```

Reality:
[image: dog]

Is there a reason why Typescript does this? Is this a bug? I realize both approaches are by definition equivalent but I would like to use my custom types for readability. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you learn more about aliases.

[Aliasing doesn’t actually create a new type - it creates a new name to refer to that type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was missing in my understanding.